# ImageMapster - how to highlight specific area ( one or two ) on load

Tags: imagemapster

I'm new to ImageMapster, I'm trying to figure out how to highlight one or two of areas onload. How do you do that?

Using the states as reference:

```
<map id="MapUSA" name="MapUSA">
  <area href="#" state="NH" full="New Hampshire" shape="rect" coords="102,36,149,83">
  <area href="#" state="VT" full="Vermont" shape="rect" coords="150,34,181,85">
</map>
```

How can I make state NH selected on load and if I have staticState: false would it be affected?

Comment: Can you also provide the javascript you're using?

Comment: Thanks reconbot. Sorry for late reply.
It seems the problem was I direct linked to the script not realizing it would cause issues. TY